# Kubernetes Dashboard by kops on AWS show only json

Tags: kubernetes, kops, kubernetes-dashboard

I've installed Kubernetes by kops on aws, and basically every function is fine so far, except for Dashboad.

I've installed it by following this URL, and received no error.
https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/addons.md#installing-kubernetes-addons

However, the browser ( chrome, firefox, safari ) just shows me json text like below. The URL is like 'https://api.clustername.xxxx.com/ui'

> "paths": [
>       "/apis",
>       "/apis/",
>       "/apis/apiextensions.k8s.io",
>       "/apis/apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1",
>       "/healthz",
>       "/healthz/etcd",
>       "/healthz/ping",
>       "/healthz/poststarthook/generic-apiserver-start-informers",
>       "/healthz/poststarthook/start-apiextensions-controllers",
>       "/healthz/poststarthook/start-apiextensions-informers",
>       "/metrics",
>       "/openapi/v2",
>       "/swagger-2.0.0.json",
>       "/swagger-2.0.0.pb-v1",
>       "/swagger-2.0.0.pb-v1.gz",
>       "/swagger.json",
>       "/swaggerapi",
>       "/version"
>     ]

I would like see the real dashboard...
What shall I do ?

Answer (score 1):

By default dashboard access this:

```
/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/http:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/
```

Check: `https://api.clustername.xxxx.com/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/http:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/`

Comment: Thanks, but I can not see my dashboard as ui yet... Insted, I got the following error.

`
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    
  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "the server could not find the requested resource",
  "reason": "NotFound",
  "details": {
    
  },
  "code": 404
}
`

Comment: Oh, sorry. Maybe this help you: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/dashboard-tutorial.html

Comment: `/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/#/login`

Answer (score 1):

> kubectl  cluster-info

Kubernetes master:- Use this url

Append that url with:-
 /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/

Username and password will be prompted on browser

> kubectl config view

you will get username :- admin (default) and password

Next we need token 
So create user by below step
https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/wiki/Creating-sample-user
create

Get token once user is created with admin access

> - kubectl -n kube-system describe secret $(kubectl -n kube-system get secret | grep admin-user | awk '{print $1}')